# MongoDB query to group by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and I want to query the mongoDB by grouping date

Data :

```
{
  "name":"Samuel",
  "place":"Boston",
  "time":"2020-2-05 5:15:10"
},
{
  "name":"John Smith",
  "place":"Amsterdam",
  "time":"2017-20-4 22:10:40"
},
{
  "name":"Darek",
  "place":"Canada",
  "time":"2020-2-05 15:23:25"
},
{
  "name":"Kenio",
  "place":"Tokyo",
  "time":"2017-20-4 10:11:02"
}
```

I want it in the below format :

```
[
   {
       "2020-2-05":[{
            "name":"Samuel",
            "place":"Boston",
            "time":"2020-2-05 5:15:10"
        },{
            "name":"Darek",
            "place":"Canada",
            "time":"2020-2-05 15:23:25"
        }]
   },
   {
        "2017-20-4":[{
            "name":"John Smith",
            "place":"Amsterdam",
            "time":"2017-20-4 22:10:40"
        },{
            "name":"Kenio",
            "place":"Tokyo",
            "time":"2017-20-4 10:11:02"
        }]
   }
]
```

Can somebody please help me as I am not getting any ideas to get the output in desired format. Really appreciate for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `$group` stage combined with some data structure manipulation is all you need:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $split: [
              "$time",
              " "
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      roots: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      newRoot: [
        {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$roots"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$newRoot"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I personally recommend you start storing the `time` field as a [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) and not as string, this will make your life much easier in the future.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rgBpbCzImgk)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom Slabbaert. It worked. Yeah next time I will make sure that I store the timestamp field as Date and not string.